# In the setting of log_format of nginx, how to use regex to parse the field?

Tags: regex, nginx, logging, format

Now I have a log_format in my nginx.conf just like:

*`log_format my_format '"my header":"$upstream_http_x_my_header"'`*

and the value of the header 'x_my_header" like "abc:123"
Then I want to add a new field just like:

```
   log_format my_format '"my header":"$upstream_http_x_my_header"'
                         '"myheader2":"$upstream_http_x_my_header.split("." ).get(1)"'
```

## get the value "123" from the "my header".

So My question is:
Does the regex is supported in the log_format?if so how can I use the regression to realize the above purpose?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello, can you explain more clearly what you've tried so far?
You can use backticks ` or four spaces to post code in a way that's easier to read. You can also check the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to use markdown to visually improve your questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have correct the format of the code.Actually, I want to use regex or program to cut the variables of nginx , such as "$remote_addr" , "$upstream_http_x_my_header".
But I'm not sure whether the regex or program is supported inner the section "log_format" in the nginx.conf.

Comment: It seems the regex in log_format is not supported.There is no this description in the documentation of Nginx.